# Prolog Arithmetic plus

Tags: prolog, addition

I've stumbled on a rather weird problem (to me).

Very easy, I want to an addition between 2 integers. I use the plus clause from [swi](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.25%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/arith.html%27%29%29)

Now when I do this (I'm calculation something in a graph)

```
plus(LatestTime,LengthPath,TimeArrive),
```

The TimeArrive variable is a physical address instead of the answer.
Now I've tried to make an other clause

```
myPlus(Var1,Var2,Result):-
    Result is Var1 + Var2.
```

And here is the same, so I'm starting to believe their is something wrong with my 2 input variables

```
LatestTime,LengthPath
```

However when I 'write' them I receive the integer instead of physical address.

Any clues? Because I'm out of idea's :)

Comment: I've fixed it with replacing the plus with a 
   TimeArrive is LatestTime + LengthPath
But still, I'm clueless about why prolog gave me a physical address instead of an integer.

Comment: It's a bit hard to guess what's going wrong without the rest of the code; I guess that an if-structure is involved or some side-effects although I cannot see how replacing myPlus/3 fixed it

Comment: What do you mean by a "physical address"?

Comment: I suspect that what you are seeing is not a "physical address" but the effect of asking for the value of an unbound (free) variable.  Of course what you actually wrote in the question is "I receive the integer instead of physical address."  This compounds the confusion as to what you want and what you are doing to attempt it.

Comment: If it is a reproducable file a bug: http://www.swi-prolog.org/Mailinglist.html

Comment: Maybe you can tell us, how you calculate the both input variables LatestTime and LengthPath. I think that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Use [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd) for expressing relations between integer values whenever possible!

In general, I think it is best to use [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd) for *all* integer calculation instead of "plain-old Prolog arithmetics via `(is)/2`---not just the ones you consider "reversible".